# How to do non-interactive oauth2 api call?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a Wordpress cron script that calls OAuth2 api at fixed intervals. The OAuth2 authorization needs a user to visit a web page and click the "Allow" button to authorize, which is impossible in non-interactive environment. I would like to know the standard way to handle this. I wish I could just put the client_id and client_secret in the php script and all done. After all, both the user and the script developer are the same: me myself, and there should be no need to do the authorization.

Comment: How so it can't be done? It's not hard if you combine [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [$http_response_header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) and [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to post credentials, grep csrf tokens, catch redirects and parse responses.

Comment: hi @RonvanderHeijden do you mean to use these functions to simulate the process of a user logs in and clicks the "Allow" button? Can you give me a sample code to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the complete auth code flow with pkce using [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [$http_response_header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) and [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

The script would have steps like:

1. build the `authorization_url` and do get request
2. detect the redirect to a login page, grep the `csrf token` from the html
3. post `username`, `password` and `csrf token` and detect redirect url to authorize page
4. parse authorize page, grep `csrf token` if any and post to accept permissions
5. detect callback url and take the `code` from the get parameters
6. post `code` and other requirements to `token_url` and decode the received tokens

I have created a script like this for an OpenId Connect project, but it does not have login and authorize pages. You can find an example here: https://github.com/ronvanderheijden/openid-connect/blob/main/example/get_tokens

Comment: Your script is a good start to implement a non-interactive client. The problem is for normal OAuth2, $redirectParams = $crawler->httpRequest($authorizationUrl,...) does not return an auth code directly.  You need to visit $authorizationUrl and click the "Allow" button, then it will redirect to $redirectUrl with the auth code.

Comment: The authorize page with allow buttons is probably just another form you can post ;)